# how can i create a function to produce a pdf document of plots

Tags: r, plot, functional-programming, tidyverse, data-manipulation

I have several plot objects that i would like to plot in a pdf. How can i edit the code below to create a function to produce the same pdf plots:

The plots have different titles 'main'.

```
pdf(file="results/sitar_df3df8_m.pdf")
plot(alsp_logbmc_sitar_m_3df, ylim = c(500,3500), main = "ALSPAC Males: df=3", xlab = "Age - y",  ylab = "BMC - g")
plot(alsp_logbmc_sitar_m_4df, ylim = c(500,3500), main = "ALSPAC Males: df=4", xlab = "Age - y",  ylab = "BMC - g")
plot(alsp_logbmc_sitar_m_5df, ylim = c(500,3500), main = "ALSPAC Males: df=5", xlab = "Age - y",  ylab = "BMC - g")
plot(alsp_logbmc_sitar_m_6df, ylim = c(500,3500), main = "ALSPAC Males: df=6", xlab = "Age - y",  ylab = "BMC - g")
plot(alsp_logbmc_sitar_m_7df, ylim = c(500,3500), main = "ALSPAC Males: df=7", xlab = "Age - y",  ylab = "BMC - g")
plot(alsp_logbmc_sitar_m_8df, ylim = c(500,3500), main = "ALSPAC Males: df=8", xlab = "Age - y",  ylab = "BMC - g")
plot(bmdcs_logbmc_sitar_m_3df, ylim = c(500,3500), main = "BMDCS Males: df=3", xlab = "Age - y",  ylab = "BMC - g")
plot(bmdcs_logbmc_sitar_m_4df, ylim = c(500,3500), main = "BMDCS Males: df=4", xlab = "Age - y",  ylab = "BMC - g")
plot(bmdcs_logbmc_sitar_m_5df, ylim = c(500,3500), main = "BMDCS Males: df=5", xlab = "Age - y",  ylab = "BMC - g")
plot(bmdcs_logbmc_sitar_m_6df, ylim = c(500,3500), main = "BMDCS Males: df=6", xlab = "Age - y",  ylab = "BMC - g")
plot(bmdcs_logbmc_sitar_m_7df, ylim = c(500,3500), main = "BMDCS Males: df=7", xlab = "Age - y",  ylab = "BMC - g")
plot(bmdcs_logbmc_sitar_m_8df, ylim = c(500,3500), main = "BMDCS Males: df=8", xlab = "Age - y",  ylab = "BMC - g")
dev.off()
```

Comment: What is the problem? I would expect that this would produce a 12-page PDF, one plot per page. (Unconfirmed without a reproducible question.)

Comment: you can use `gsub` to get the first and last bit of the object name into your "main".

Comment: Could you show how gsub would work?

Answer (score 0):

**Assumption:** First argument of each plot in your sample plot function call is dataframe.

**Steps**

1. Create a list of data frame for which you need to plot.[similar to below]

   `ldf <- list(alsp_logbmc_sitar_m_3df, alsp_logbmc_sitar_m_4df, alsp_logbmc_sitar_m_5df)`
2. Create a vector of names for each plot in the same sequence.

   `plot_name <- paste0("ALSPAC Males: df=", 3:5)`
3. Call below function.

   `plot_df_to_pdf_func <-
     function(list_of_dfs, pdf_name = "stack.pdf") {
       ldf <- list_of_dfs
       pdf(file = pdf_name)
       for (i in seq_along(ldf)) {
         name <- plot_name[i]
         df <- ldf[[i]]
         plot(df,
              main = name,
              xlab = "Age - y",
              ylab = "BMC - g")
       }
       dev.off()
     }`

   `plot_df_to_pdf_func(ldf)`

**Disclaimer:** The function may not be the finest version. Please improvise as per your use. Also, ***all suggestions are welcome.***

Thank you!!!